# Accounting/currency symbols extraction using formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a column in excel which contains data in multiple accounting format. 
e.g.
USD 25
INR 140
CNY 74

in the formula bar it shows only the value and not the symbol. could you please help me to get formula to extract these symbols from cell. I dont want to run VBA code or create user function.

Comment: The information about the currency symbol used in an accounting format is not available to standard Excel functions.  In VBA, you can either examine the `numberformat` property of the cell, or the `.text` property of the cell.

Comment: Using VBA is possible but I am not allowed to use any macro. currently I am coping the data, pasting the data in notepad and then pasting as TEXT to get my work done. Need to find formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

With the below user defined function you get the value as a text including the currency symbol:

```
Function GetTextValue(ByVal arg As Range) As String
     '//Cell value (or top left cell value if range is more than one cell)
     GetTextValue = arg.Cells(1, 1).Text 
End Function
```

With a substitute you might replace the value and get only the currency:

=SUBSTITUTE(C2;TEXT(B2;"#.##0,00");"")

..

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use Text Function to get the cell formatting.

```
=Text(A1,"CopyPasteA1CellFormattingHere")
```

Change A1 to your desired cell reference.

Comment: Don't know who given -1 to my post.  But it indicates that they can't understand the value of the given solution.

Comment: How does your formula work to extract the currency type used?  It seems to me that you would have to know the currency type in order to use your function.  Perhaps an example would be helpful.

Comment: @Sixthsense, the above formula wont work. Currency value could be anything and it doesnt appear in formula bar as well. e.g. in Formula bar, I can see 25 but in Cell it is showing USD 25, second row might have different currency. If I copy the format of only one cell then result will be incorrect. e.g. first row has 25 USD, second has 3000 INR. if I use this formula, second row also reflect as 3000 USD which is not right.
I am still not figured out how to get the accounting symbol through formula and I cant even use any custom function or Macro to get it done.